# Parsing JSON in Javascript Function - Uncaught Syntax Exception

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, model-view-controller

I have a Javascript function contained within an MVC view that is supposed to take in an object value from the ViewModel, encode it into JSON, then display to the user a dialog box with the resulting JSON.

```
function getObjectInformation(obj) {
    var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
        message: JSON.parse(obj)
    });
};
```

And the method I am using to pass the JSON into this function is:

```
<li><a href="javascript:getObjectInformation(@Json.Encode(Model.Concierge).ToString())">Concierge</a></li>
```

I read articles on using `JSON.parse()` to accomplish this, but each time I pass that function the JSON string I'd like to parse I get the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here, as the examples I've been seeing online show using JSON.parse() in the same way.

Comment: Could you post what Model.Concierge is?

Comment: Do you need the `ToString()`? `Json.Encode` might already do that

Comment: First, try adding quotes around the `@Json.Encode(....)` call. Also ToString() should not be needed. If that does not help, then In `getObjectInformation(obj)`, add `console.log(obj);` or `alert(obj);` as the first line and edit the question with the output. Hint: `obj` should be a string.

Comment: its your input that is causing the issue not the function

Comment: Adding the quotes definitely helped! Thank you for the comment :)